# Check record state of a database entry

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I'm writing an hardware inventory application. I get data from a computer through WMI and write it to a database with LINQ.

Eventually I end up with a record like:

```
ID  HOSTNAME    OS         Memory   
 1  myHostname  Windows 7  4Gb
```

Now imagine I add some memory to this computer and the next time the application finds it, it will have the information from this computer updated and will try to write it to the database.

Before writing I check if my `Hostname` is already present on database (it is the `Primary Key`), in this case it already exists. So now, do I query the database for this hostname and get all information I have for this computer and create an object with it and compare it with the object I got from WMI ?

Isn't there any way to create a value on my table based on each record information and then have LINQ to create one based on the WMI object and compare each other?

Sorry if the text is a little confusing, hope you guys can help me out with this.

Comment: Can't *really* tell what exactly you are asking, but I think the answer is this:  "Typically in this use case a stored procedure called insertORupdate would be written that would perform the appropriate action."

Comment: Yes, your question is a bit confusing. Have a look at Entity Framework Code First which may help you solve your problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
var entry = yourContext.YourTable.SingleOrDefault(e => e.HostName == someHostName);
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to query for the `WMI_object.hostname == hostname`

this makes code something like that:

```
Dataobject obj = (select o from entity.objects where o.hostname == WMI_object.hostname);
obj.memory = WMI_object.memory;
entity.SaveChanges();
```